# Export neo4j database in json file

Tags: json, database, neo4j, export

I want to export Neo4j graph database in JSON file.

This is a Export JSON button in Neo4j web UI version as shown in attached image below.
[image]

But what is the equivalent command for the same task in Neo4j shell.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The `json` exported by the browser is exactly what is getting sent to the [transactional cypher endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html). This is not directly accessible via `neo4j-shell`, but you might use any command line `http` client like [`cURL`](http://curl.haxx.se/) or [`httpie`](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie).

For httpie it's as simple as:

```
 http -b -j localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit statements:='[{"statement": "<your cypher goes here>", "parameters": { cypher parameters go here as map }]'
```

However it is simple to extend `neo4j-shell`, see Michael's [`neo4j-shell-tools`](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools).

Answer (score 0):

Both using the api and the shell tools are good solutions. But they don't seem scalable, in a containerized environment it will be kind of difficult to automate this process.

The [Geoff](https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki/Geoff) package is really great and there are tools as this in other languages too, if needed. The speed it reads and dumps the data made me more confident in this solution as opposed to the others.

Later Edit:
I noticed you are looking for the specific Json Format, I found another [cool library](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/GraphSON-Reader-and-Writer-Library) that can help with that pretty quick if you need.