# Exporting Cypher result graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Cypher query that results in a graph (a small subgraph of the complete Neo4j database). I would like to export that graph and send it to a colleague who does not have access to the database and who doesn't have Neo4j installed. In fact she doesn't know about Neo4j and Cypher at all, but she does know about graphs. I want her to be able to view and interact with the graph much in the same way that I can do in the Neo4j browser environment. At least, she should be able to see all labels and properties attached to nodes.

Exporting to SVG doesn't do the job because node properties are lost.

Any tips?
Thanks much.

Comment: This is a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608316/export-neo4j-database-in-json-file). My take: the Neo4j web interface provides an option to export the results of a particular query to JSON, which isn't easy to process but could work. You can also use the [shell tools](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#export) export to GraphML or a CSV (with the schema defined by the Cypher query).

Comment: Using APOC, you can also export to [Geoff](https://neo4j.com/blog/apoc-database-integration-import-export-cypher/) - this could be a good fit for someone using graph analytics tools.